# Grails- how to call in gsp file to a function which is in js file through onchange event?

Tags: javascript, grails

I have a GSP which contains a select element:

```
<select class="form-control companyNameSelect" id="companyNameSelect" name="companySelected"  onchange="companyTeam()">
    <g:each in="${companies }" var="company" >
    <option value="${company?.id }">${company?.companyname}</option>
    </g:each>
</select>
```

The companyTeam function is in another file (js file) which the gsp "know".
For some reason I got the following error:
"Uncaught ReferenceError: companyTeam  is not defined"

Comment: Where are you using `radioFunc`?

Comment: @Abs- in the js file

Comment: May be it is an scope issue, you can try `window.radioFunc=function(...)`

Comment: The error is regarding the companyTeam ....I edited it

Answer (score 0):

Try to bind it from the js:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#companyNameSelect").on('change', companyTeam());
});
```